# Can I use "on this occasion" to start a sentence?

Tags: expression-choice, sentence-starts

Can I use *on this occasion* to start a sentence? For example:

> I worked for three years as administrator of XXXX. **On this occasion** I managed. .  . .

Answer (score 5):

In the example given, a three-year span of time would not be considered an occasion. If, on the other hand, the previous sentence referred to some specific event, such as, "During my tenure as administrator of XXXX, the organization declared bankruptcy. On this occasion I managed . . . ," then beginning the next sentence with *On this occasion* would be acceptable.

Comment: Answers the question _and_ corrects the example very nicely.

Comment: @ Serena, You are welcome.